# Calculate for each combination of ORIGIN, DEST and DAY_OF_WEEK the median value of ARR_DELA

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to coding and at the moment struggling to come up with a line of code to help me crack this question.

In my data there is a list of flights that have taken place with their delay times, and flight origin and destinations. I would like advice on what sort of code I should use to find the median value of the ARR_DELAY for each combination of origin, destination and day of the week.

[image]

Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `groupby`

```
flights.groupby(['ORIGIN', 'DEST', 'DAY_OF_WEEK']).median()
```

you could also fill your NaNs with 0s first if NaNs means no delay :

```
flights = flights.fillna(0)
flights.groupby(['ORIGIN', 'DEST', 'DAY_OF_WEEK']).median()
```